# Where exactly does the root directory exist in the linux filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems

In Windows each drive has a letter and file paths start with a drive letter. so my home directory is inside `C:\Users`.

In linux the OS is installed into the main partition which is say `/dev/sda1` which is inside the root directory. So is `/home` inside `/dev/sda1`?

Also root has to be inside sda1 which is the drive the OS is installed in which is a loop, so how does that work?

Comment: define "where" in this context? Windows and linux use different conceptual approaches to mounting storage for use, so they are not an apples>apples comparision. as for your /home/ dir, it may be on /dev/sda1, but it is quite common for an admin to configure homes to exist on another disk, and just be mounted to /home/. In linux, all mounted volumes are mounted to somewhere in / but that doesn't necessarily mean that they are on the same disk.

Comment: You're conflating several meanings of `sda1`. When used as a fully defined path, such as `/dev/sda1`, this is usually intended to refer to the actual partition (or its contents) of a physical drive (i.e. a mass storage device).  When used by itself, i.e. just `sda1`, this is usually intended to refer to either (a) the device node (i.e. a special type of directory entry) in the **/dev** subdirectory that allows access to a device/partition through its device driver, or (b) the contents of the partition, or (c) the filesystem contained in that partition.

Comment: "*In linux the OS is installed into the main partition ... Also root has to be inside sda1 ...*" - Such dogmatic statements are not true or accurate. Linux strives to be flexible. The device or partition that contains a root filesystem can be specified in the command line when booting the kernel.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that Windows allows you to assign multiple letters to a single partition, or to mount it as a folder on some other partition. You can have SSD as a D: drive, with 10TB HDD mounted as D:\Storage and M.2 SSD as D:\Games.
That's also more-or-less what Linux does, but it defaults to mounting as directories, instead of letters.

Comment: Where exactly is does "My Computer" directory exist on Windows?

Comment: @tpimh "My Computer" links to the partition that contains the Windows installation including user account folders. It is most commonly defined as the C: drive, but it doesn't need to be.

Comment: One thing to ponder upon is that Windows supportes multiple drives and can be installed on other drives than C:  How does Windows know how to find the drive with itself on it and how does it know what drive letters the other disks have?

Comment: It is wherever you put it ;-).

Comment: I don't believe that "My Computer" exists on disk anywhere. it is purely a feature of the shell, to make it easy to look at all your disk mounts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm providing this as a simple answer commensurate with the question asked, in the hopes that it is accessible to OP. the other answers are great as is, but get a little complex.

So first off, there is a bit of a terminology collision.

Your system has a "root partition" where the OS files are stored. That partition is not actually `/` however. `/` doesn't actually "exist" anywhere when the system is off. when you boot it up, `/` comes into existence out of nothingness.

`/` is an abstraction used for the most primary level of the storage hierarchy that a Linux system can address. all storage mounted on that system is going to be mounted to a location somewhere in `/`.

So when the system boots, it establishes the idea of `/` for the purpose of mounting storage on it. The most important storage it mounts is is the volume that the OS is stored on, which is commonly called "the root partition", and I believe that is the source of your confusion. The "root partition" is mounted on `/` so the name makes sense from a normal perspective, but makes questions like yours awkward. This is also why there isn't a "loop" as you put it. The root partition just contains the files that should be mounted in `/`, not `/`  itself.

One way to conceptualize the difference is, let's say I took the drive containing "root partition" of my Ubuntu laptop out, and installed it on my Debian PC so I could fix a data corruption problem. I choose to mount it to `/mnt/laptop-drive/`. Just because the partition was `/` on my laptop does not mean it is `/` on my PC. My PC already has a `/` and it has Debian on it. So the "root partition" is just a partition like any other. if it "contained" `/` then I would not be able to mount it to an arbitrary path on another system, but instead it just contains "the files that should be in `/`". See the difference?

Part of the confusion comes from comparisons with Windows. Windows presents each drive that is mounted as its own stand-alone thing. Try thinking of it like this: instead of a having a collection of independent mounted disks it's more like the c and d and whatever other drives are mounted to the OS at `\` so it's more like `\c:\`, `\d:\`, ..., `\n:\`, so that it works the same way Linux does. There is a most primary level to the storage hierarchy that contains the disks that get mounted by the OS.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "*`/` is an abstraction used for the lowest level of the storage hierarchy*" - I think I understand what you're trying to convey, but it's likely to be misunderstood by others. Root, `/`, is typically portrayed as the *top* of the filesystem tree structure; i.e. the top or highest level. Graphs (representing trees) are drawn going downward, the inverse of biological trees.

Comment: Depending on how you ask the question, / does exist. Every filesystem has a root directory which contains the files that will exist on its mountpoint. So when you mount / guess what appears? The "loop" is broken by device major & minor numbers. In the simplest case, the root filesystem is passed as a major and minor number to the kernel.

Comment: _"the root partition just contains the files that should be mounted in /, not /  itself."_, well, not really, since the root directory is a directory itself, and it's very much contained in the filesystem that gets mounted, just like any other directory. The root directory of the filesystem mounted on `/` becomes the `/` directory itself. (Consider e.g. the inode and device numbers that `stat` prints for `/`)

Comment: Also, the idea that `/` as some abstract entity is created from nowhere, and then the root filesystem mounted on top of it is intriguing, but I've had the impression that it's impossible to run Linux without _something_ mounted on `/`. If that's indeed still the case, that "initial" `/` becomes a total non-entity, you can never see it or do anything with it, because it's always hidden under the mounted filesystem.

Comment: @ilkkachu, so your argument is that a mount point and the top-level directory of any volume mounted on that mount point are the same?

Comment: @FrankThomas, well, mounting a filesystem on, say, `/foo` hides the original `/foo` and makes all references to `/foo` access the root directory of the mounted fs. That's evident in pretty much everything `stat` shows, not just the device and inode numbers, but also the owner and permissions come from those of the mounted filesystem. Of course the original would still exist on the lower fs (and the space taken by files within shows as used in `df`), so they're not the same directory. But the name `/foo` refers to the one mounted on top.

Comment: but if you unmount /foo, what you say is no longer true. /foo is still there but the volume is not there. likewise, you could mount the volume you call "bar" to your /foo mount point and once again, we prove that the mount point /foo is not existentially the same as the TLD for the volumes foo or bar. the mount point must exist before a volume can be mounted on it. that means they cannot be the same thing. as such / must exist before the root partition is mounted on it, and if you dual boot, your system may have more than one root partition that gets mounted to /, depending on what you boot.

Answer (score 8):

> Where exactly does the root directory exist in the linux filesystem?

On a typical Linux installation where the computer has a storage device, such as a hard drive or solid state drive, the root filesystem will reside on a partition of that storage device.

The entirety of the directory tree of a Linux system can be located on a single partition.

Optionally, some directories could reside on separate partitions. In this case the root file system is mounted first and then these partitions will be mounted on top of that.

For example, a particular Linux installation could require that the `/home` directory be located on a separate partition. In this case the storage device could be setup to contain two partitions, which could be recognized by the Linux kernel as `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`. During boot process the `/dev/sda1` will be mounted as `/` and then `/dev/sda2` will be mounted as `/home`.

The partition for the `/home` directory could reside on a separate storage device, let's say on a second partition of an additional hard drive - `/dev/sdb2`.

---

On more sophisticated Linux installations the root directory could exist in RAM completely. For example, the root directory can be packed into a [SquashFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) image, which is copied from a remote network location during boot process and mounted in read-only mode as `/`.

Or the SquashFS image could reside on a USB drive and mounted as `/` from there. In this case the root file system exists on the said USB drive.

---

The root file system could exist as a [Network File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) mount, in which case the filesystem exists on a separate machine and the Linux kernel mounts it during boot process.

---

Executing command `mount` without arguments should list all currently mounted filesystems. Also, this list exists in the `/proc/mounts` file. Among the entries there should be one for the root filesystem - which has `/` as its mountpoint, for example:

```
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

With this it should be possible to see where the root file system exists for this particular system.

---

**EDIT:**

> Also root has to be inside sda1 which is the drive the OS is installed in which is a loop, so how does that work?

If we assume that the OS root filesystem is located on the `/dev/sda1` partition, the fact that the `sda1` entry is located in the `/dev` directory does not create a chicken-egg type dependency.

None of the entries in the `/dev` directory are regular files and they are not stored on a storage device, but they are simply listed there. This directory serves as a location where the Linux system provides entries for various devices, so that they can be referred to when used in other contexts.

A crude analogy to this "loop" problem in the Windows world would be to think: "How come the `C:\` drive is listed in the device manager while the device manager itself has to be loaded from the `C:\` drive"? This is very crude analogy, but it should demonstrate the point that the device manager is a place where devices are displayed in a Windows system. In the context of this comparison it can be said (in very imprecise terms) that the `/dev` directory in a Linux system is a counterpart of the device manager in Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to system booting 101.

UEFI bios looks in the firmware variables and sees it says "run WDC100037/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi" where WDC100037 is your hard disk serial number. `grubx64.efi` in turn reads grub.cfg from the same directory which tells it how to find `/boot`. In most cases this will be an fs UUID; so it just checks all partitions on all hard disks to see which one contains /boot and the path from the root directory of that filesystem (every filesystem has a root directory) to `grub.cfg` and reads that in.

`grub.cfg` is this ridiculously over-engineered way of saying "load this kernel with this initramfs and this command line" and jump to it. In almost all cases the kernels reside under /boot and that's where they are read in from. The kernel header has free slots for the device major and minor numbers. grub can and will use these; however most of the time it would rather do something else.

The most common way is initramfs contains udev and mount_root. What happens in kernel booting is a new ramdrive is created out of nowhere, and initramfs is unarchived into it (the logical equivalent of gunzip | cpio -i). Then `/init` is executed, which starts udev and parses the kernel command line looking for `root=`, waits for that device to be created, then mounts it on /root, and finally does `exec chroot /root /sbin/init`.

If there's no initrd, the kernel tries to parse its command line on its own and identify the root= argument. If it's something simple enough it just mounts that device. The parsing mode here is very simple. It recognizes things like /dev/sd[a-f][1-16] and turns those into major and minor numbers and mounts it. This transform might not agree with what is in /dev; and the kernel has no way of checking. Failing in that it just looks at the major and minor number in its header, and mounts that. If that's still 0 or the mount fails, it panics.

If you look at the /dev/sda entry with a hex editor on the disk device you will find that it occupies zero bytes. It's a block device node, and the rdev field tells the kernel which one. On most systems /dev is some kind of ramdisk; however a physical /dev is possible. I used to leave it populated on my / until this became too unstable due to dynamic device detection.

The idea of device nodes is critical. In fact it's so critical that even Windows has it. \.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 is your hard disk. No you can't say something like \.\PHYSICALDRIVE0\C:\Users ; that's not how that works. Device nodes are the disk device as a single file not as a mounted filesystem. Windows can mount a filesystem on a path; it's just so rarely done you're not used to seeing it.

Comment: grub.cfg isn't needed at all in modern EFI systems -- the kernel itself is an EFI executable, and can have config parameters &c bundled in; systemd also has its own bootloader, based on gummiboot, that likewise is a lot smaller / simpler / more modern, and can be used if for some reason one doesn't like the boot menu provided natively by your local EFI firmware.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the other answers are quite good, but I noticed that none of them fully explain the difference between partitions, mount points, and the filesystem. Based on your question I think that's at the root of your confusion (no pun intended!) so let me try to clear it up.

(Fair warning to pedants: I'm sacrificing some precision in what follows to keep the post from getting too complicated.)

A partition on a drive is just a sequence of bytes stored on that drive. I don't know about Windows, but on Linux, you can examine those bytes by reading from files like `/dev/sda1` or so on - those files are special "device files" that (among other purposes) give the system direct access to the raw content of the partition. For instance, I have a partition which happens to be readable at `/dev/sdc1`, and here is a display of the first 256 bytes of that partition:

```
$ sudo head -c 256 /dev/sdc1 | hexdump
0000000 5652 1bbe e881 0139 bf5e 81f4 8b66 832d
0000010 087d 0f00 e284 8000 ff7c 7400 6646 1d8b
0000020 8b66 044d 3166 b0c0 397f 0845 037f 458b
0000030 2908 0845 0166 6605 5583 0004 04c7 0010
0000040 4489 6602 5c89 6608 4c89 c70c 0644 7000
0000050 c750 0444 0000 42b4 13cd 820f 00af 00bb
0000060 eb70 6666 458b 6604 c009 850f 0097 8b66
0000070 6605 d231 f766 8834 0a54 3166 66d2 74f7
0000080 8804 0b54 4489 3b0c 0844 797d 048b 442a
0000090 390a 0845 037f 458b 2908 0845 0166 6605
00000a0 5583 0004 548a c00d 06e2 4c8a fe0a 08c1
00000b0 8ad1 0c6c 525a 748a 500b 00bb 8e70 31c3
00000c0 b4db cd02 7213 8c46 8ec3 0a45 c158 05e0
00000d0 4501 600a c11e 03e0 c189 ff31 f631 db8e
00000e0 f3fc 1fa5 23be e881 0057 8361 087d 0f00
00000f0 2485 83ff 0cef 16e9 beff 8125 42e8 5a00
0000100
```

You can do the same kind of thing to view the raw byte content of any partition on your system: take any program that can display binary data (`hexdump`, `od`, `base64`, whatever you like) and have it read from `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sdd3` or whatever partition you want to examine. (Of course, be careful that you're not *writing* to the partition when you do this; that could break your system!)

As you might imagine, partitions with filesystems on them won't just have any random sequence of bytes. Their content will form a special sequence of bytes that can be interpreted by a piece of software called a filesystem driver. There are many different filesystem drivers, each of which recognizes its own special sequences of bytes. But what they all have in common is that they interpret their respective byte sequences as a hierarchy of folders and files. When you mount a partition, the kernel tells the filesystem driver "go look at these bytes and tell me the file hierarchy that represents", then it builds that file hierarchy in your computer's memory and makes it appear as directories and files that you can use.

I want to emphasize that: **directories and files exist in your computer's memory**, whereas partitions are just sequences of bytes that specify which directories and files should exist and what their contents are.

Most filesystem drivers use highly optimized sequences of bytes that are hard for humans to interpret, but you could just as well have one that interprets bytes in a human-readable text file. For example, suppose you make this snippet of JSON:

```json
{
  "file1": "here is a string which is the contents of file1",
  "directory1": {
    "file2": "this string is the contents of file2",
    "file3": "and this string is the contents of file3"
  }
}
```

You can save this to a file on disk - say, you could call it `sdj1.json` - and it's just some bytes. But if you have [a filesystem driver capable of interpreting these bytes as directories and files](https://mgree.github.io/ffs/), you can mount it:

```
$ mkdir mount-point
$ ffs.linux --in-place --mount mount-point sdj1.json &
```

and then, presto, you have files and directories whose contents are determined by the bytes from that JSON file.

```
$ ls mount-point/
directory1  file1
$ cat mount-point/file1
here is a string which is the contents of file1
$ ls mount-point/directory1/
file2  file3
$ rm mount-point/directory1/file3
$ echo "I am replacing the contents of file3 with this string" >mount-point/directory1/file3
$ cat mount-point/directory1/file3
I am replacing the contents of file3 with this string
$ umount mount-point
$ cat sdj1.json
{"directory1":{"file2":"this string is the contents of file2","file3":"I am replacing the contents of file3 with this string"},"file1":"here is a string which is the contents of file1"}
```

This is basically what's going on with your partition `/dev/sda1` and your filesystem.

> In linux the OS is installed into the main partition which is say `/dev/sda1` which is inside the root directory. So is `/home` inside `/dev/sda1`?

It's not really the case that `/home` is *inside* `/dev/sda1`, just as it's not really the case that `mount-point/directory1` is *inside* `sdj1.json`. Your `/dev/sda1` or `sdj1.json` is just a source of bytes; it doesn't *contain* any files or folders. But it does contain (or really, provide access to) the bytes that your system can use to determine what is inside `/home`.

> Also root has to be inside sda1 which is the drive the OS is installed in which is a loop, so how does that work?

Again, the root directory `/` isn't *inside* sda1, kind of like how `mount-point` isn't *inside* `sdj1.json`, but the reason is a little different in this case. Actually, there are two differences:

First, when you mount a partition, you need somewhere to mount it, basically some kind of name that the system uses to know that you're referring to something in that partition. In Windows, that name is a drive letter. In Linux, that name is a path to some directory, i.e. the "mount point". In the commands I posted earlier, when I used a path like `mount-point/directory1/file3`, Linux was able to look up that `mount-point` was the mount point of a filesystem, because it has (effectively) a table in the kernel showing which partitions are mounted on which paths. You can view that table on a Linux system by looking at `/proc/mounts`:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts
/dev/root / ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
[...omitted...]
sdj1 /home/diazona/tmp/ffs-test/mount-point fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
```

This is how Linux knows that, when I ask for a file or something that lives inside `/home/diazona/tmp/ffs-test/mount-point`, it needs to ask the filesystem driver that I used to mount that JSON file.

The second reason is what [Frank's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1834317/2419) explained: the root directory `/` is a little special. You may have noticed the chicken-and-egg problem here: if you need a directory to mount a partition, but you need a partition to tell you that a directory exists, what comes first? Well, that's where it comes in handy that directories and files only exist in your computer's memory, because you actually *don't* need a partition on a hard drive or SSD in order for a directory to exist. The kernel can just do the thing in memory that corresponds to making a directory, and thereafter, that directory exists. This is basically what happens early in the process of starting up a Linux system to create `/`. Then the kernel looks for a partition on your drive, the root partition (which is specified by a command-line argument to the kernel, more or less... that's a long story which is partially explained by [Joshua's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1834334/2419)), and mounts that partition on `/`. As I mentioned before, the filesystem driver uses the content of the partition to tell the system what files and directories exist under `/`, things like `/bin` and `/usr` and so on. In Windows, this process happens a little differently, but the general idea is the same: the system creates `C:` in memory and uses the bytes from a particular partition to tell it what files and directories should exist inside that drive.

Comment: What filesystem is /dev/sdc1? That hexdump doesn't look particularly sensible. It's almost like it's bootloader code not the start of a filesystem. (Most Linux filesystems don't have anything in the first 1K so there's a place to put a pre-EFI bootloader).

Comment: It might be bootloader code. I just grabbed a random partition whose content didn't start with all zeros. Let me edit to avoid implying that it's a filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux the /dev folder contains "files" of your partitions and the entire disk:

1. sda - this is the file for the first entire disk
2. sda1 - this is one partition on the disk labelled "sda"
3. sdb - this is the second entire disk

These are not real files, but reading them lets you read the raw disk from start to finish. That's why these device files can also be used to clone raw disks.

Windows also has this but it's hidden.

- \Device\HarddiskVolume1 - this is a device partition in Windows.

These also let you read the raw disks but not from the command line, you need an actual programming language to access these devices.

What the operating system does:
The operating system mounts these devices to a specific location.
The default boot partition mount locations:

- Windows: `C:\`
- Linux, MacOS, Android and iOS: `\`
- MacOS also has: \Volumes\VolumeName

Other partitions can optionally be mounted in custom locations:

- Windows: C:\SomeNTFSMountPoint
- Linux: \mnt\CustomMountPoint
- MacOS: \Volumes\CustomMountPoint

The answers to your questions:

Is /home inside /dev/sda1?

Yes, /home is inside /dev/sda1, but not in the shape of a file or folder you can normally view in your file explorer. /home inside /dev/sda1 is the most raw form of /home, namely binary. The 1s and 0s that make up /home (in the master file table) are stored in sda1.

How can /dev/sda1 be inside the root if the root is inside /dev/sda1?

This might seem weird at first but it makes sense. Linux has fake files. These files don't actually exist but they appear like files to make it easy to access them from the terminal which is very prominent in Linux. That means that `/dev/sda1` is mounted to `/` but a "shortcut" to the raw partition is created under `/dev/` so it looks like the partition is inside itself but it's not because sda1 isn't a file, it's a fake shortcut pretending to be a file. The read and write operations done to this fake file are forwarded to your raw partition.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of every filesystem as having a special "bottom" directory. That directory doesn't really have a name, but we'll call it `.` for now. So for instance your Windows boot partition has files at `.\Users`, `.\Windows`, `.\pagefile.sys`, etc. When Windows boots up, it "attaches" that unnamed `.` folder to `C:`. From now on, `C:\Users` means "the file at `.\Users` in the filesystem labelled `C:`." If you were to boot a different partition, Windows might decide to attach the first filesystem to `D:` instead. `D:\Users` is still accessing the same files, it just has a different label. This is why you can change Drive Letters if you know where to look: you're not moving any files, you're just changing the label for the filesystem. (You can change the label for your boot partition away from `C:` but it's kind of a bad idea.)

Linux works a lot like this, but filesystems attach to directories instead of drive letters. Your root filesystem is just a filesystem that contains stuff like `./usr`, `./home`, `./etc`. You could mount this filesystem on `/mnt`, and then `/mnt/usr` would mean "the file at `./usr` in the filesystem mounted on `/mnt`." When the kernel boots, it doesn't even have `/`, so as a special case it finds your root filesystem and attaches it there. To the kernel `/` just means "the root filesystem I picked at boot."

As noted, Linux lets you mount stuff on any directory, so it can get a little complicated. You could have a USB drive mounted on `/home/foo/mnt`, where `/home` is a separate home partition on your hard disk. Then you have 3 separate filesystems: your root partition on `/`, the home partition on `/home`, and the USB drive on `/home/foo/mnt`.

`/dev` is weird. It's actually a special filesystem called `devfs` that only exists in kernel memory. None of the files in it exist, but the kernel knows what devices they refer to. `/dev/sda1` means something like "the first partition on the first SCSI device". It's only a label for the device though, not a folder. To access the files, you have to mount that device to a folder.

Answer (score 2):

> In linux the OS is installed into the main partition which is say /dev/sda1 which is inside the root directory. So is /home inside /dev/sda1?

It's inside the device that /dev/sda1 represents, but it's not *literally* inside /dev/sda1. The items in /dev aren't the actual devices – they're only pointers into in-kernel objects, which exist regardless of /dev. It's kind of like an *address book* for devices.

(Windows has a similar thing: /dev/sda1 is `\\.\Device\Harddisk0Partition1`.)

But in addition to that, the whole /dev isn't physically part of your `/`; it's a separate virtual filesystem that is mounted sometime during boot. Your real partition only contains an empty directory onto which the virtual "devtmpfs" filesystem is mounted. (You can see this in `findmnt`.)

> Also root has to be inside sda1 which is the drive the OS is installed in which is a loop, so how does that work?

Due to the general flexibility of Linux, there are several answers, in particular depending on whether your Linux distribution uses something called an "initramfs" the process can go two entirely different ways:

- Without an initramfs: Mounting of `/` is done entirely by the kernel itself.

  The kernel doesn't need to go through /dev because it's what *creates* the device nodes under /dev to begin with; therefore names like "sda1" are already known internally to the kernel even before they show up in /dev.

  (Again: The items in /dev aren't the actual devices; they're just pointers, and the devices exist regardless of them.)

  So the kernel can just take a shortcut, interpreting the "root=/dev/sda1" parameter in a different way without any relation to the file­system: it just discards the whole "/dev/" part and looks for a device that it internally calls "sda1".
- With an initramfs: Mounting of `/` is done by… a whole another mini-Linux system that exists in RAM and works as the initial, temporary `/` until the real one is mounted.

  There is an `initrd.img` file somewhere in your /boot which contains a small Linux root, just enough to include a few kernel modules and tools like /bin/mount. It is pre-loaded into memory *by your bootloader* (in the same way as the kernel itself is loaded), so the kernel doesn't need to know where to load it from.

  When the kernel starts, it mounts an empty *memory* filesystem (kind of like a "RAM disk") at `/` and unpacks the contents of the (already pre-loaded) initramfs into it. Since the initramfs is a fully-functioning Linux root and even has its own /dev, it can just `mount` /dev/sda1 like normal, then use a special call to swap the original in-memory `/` with your real one.